# SED RegEx Between Multiple Same Characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How would I grab this following title text between all this tags and symbols ?

What I need to grab:

```
Some Title Here v1.2.3 Some Other Description About the Title in Here
```

Example source code:

```
<body><pre>=============================================================
Some Title Here v1.2.3 Some Other Description About the Title in Here
=============================================================

some other data here but I don't care about it ...

</pre></body></html>
```

I've tried doing this, but it grabs whole top part too before pre tag even, but bellow part seems to work fine, except that it also grabs = symbols.

```
sed -n '/<pre>=/,/=/p
```

Result from this above sed code is:

```
<body><pre>=============================================================
Some Title Here v1.2.3 Some Other Description About the Title in Here
=============================================================
```

Any feedback about this would be apreceated. Thank you so much, and as always StackOverflow is the best community for Q's and A's =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -n '/<pre>=/,/=/ { //!p }' file.txt
```

Result:

```
Some Title Here v1.2.3 Some Other Description About the Title in Here
```

Explanation:

`//!p` simply tells `sed` to ignore the last match.

Answer (score 0):

Updating OP's solution:

```
$ sed -n '/<pre>=/,/=/{/=$/d;p;}' file 
Some Title Here v1.2.3 Some Other Description About the Title in Here
```

From the range of lines selected, delete those ending with =, so you are left with the line in-between.

Comment: This one works but still grabs everything before and pre tag and also equals (=) symbols bellow. But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^<body><pre>=\+$/,/^=\+$/!d;//d' file
```